# Gmail SMTP rejecting my login

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvuQ\n5.7.14 hjav3RshZ9XqmApuN6mVTPJ_3AZUJEkiniSxdgdVMrgEpKpUtHi8_oCjzuOA9pkhGMyTrs\n5.7.14 fuSX9EuvWudU00Q1KXZgY4rZ1I5ZEEDOqvVMl7bOQitwyb_sYdgPA3tJC7_xpUN1zDC6Ib\n5.7.14 MjA2mM_oMdCOeCpodh-13LwLFlyzmZALwg2uu522OxG0NH74B2hafBfT2F1XK0lXCz1hce\n5.7.14 3yugD0g> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14 Learn more at\n5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 bw2sm40059670pad.46 - gsmtp')
```

I am getting the above error from the below script. And yes I have verified that I am using my correct credentials. All I want to do is send an email from a script! Has anyone run into this issue before?

```
import smtplib

FROMADDR = "my.real.address@gmail.com"
LOGIN    = FROMADDR
PASSWORD = "my.real.password"
TOADDRS  = ["my.real.address@gmail.com"]
SUBJECT  = "Test"

msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (FROMADDR, ", ".join(TOADDRS), SUBJECT) )
msg += "some text\r\n"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Do you have 2 factors auth enabled? if so you need to generate an application password https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en

Comment: I do not have 2 factor enabled

Comment: Did you try to follow the url in the error message? where does that leads you to ?

Comment: have you used the script successfully before?

Comment: This is a brand new script. And the page is https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754. It is not helpful

Comment: I am able to send through Yahoo just fine but I would like to determine the issue with Gmail. My password does contain quotes (both ' and ") and they are escaped. I am wondering if the issue could be something with that? I can't think of anything else

Comment: I have a working gmail script if you want it, it is just a basic script to send an email but it works.You can compare and see where yours is failing.

Comment: I guess I can try that, sure

Comment: I added an answer, you are missing a elho before you send the password. Try that and see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this ended up being changing my gmail password. I never did figure out which special characters were throwing everything off, but I just generated a new password and had no problems with this after that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable 'Access for less secure apps' option in your Google account security section.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()  # you are missing elho to establish communication with server
server.login(username, password)

# Full script
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

from_address = 'you@gmail.com'
to_address = 'you80@gmail.com'
text = 'test message sent from Python'
username = '****'
password = '****'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address
msg['Subject'] = 'Foo'
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

If you have not logged in using your browser since the error messages, you should also try that as if you had a number of unsuccessful logins you will have to enter a captcha,

Comment: Same result. Gmail just keeps blocking it!

Comment: Tried it. Gmail still rejects me. I guess I'll just use Yahoo from now on

Comment: I had the unsecure app support activated, no 2-factor-auth, but was missing the Captcha thingy: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229